# Android whats the best way to name a boolean function that also performs logic?

Tags: java, android, coding-style, refactoring

this is related to API design, on Android:

I want to have good coding style, and yes, i realize this is very minor, but let's say i have something like:

```
public boolean validateSomeInputAndDoLogicIfNot(Context context, MyObject myObject) {
    if (someObject.isCaseOne()) {
        Toast.makeToast...
        return true;
    } else if (someObject.isCaseTwo()) {
        doSomethingCrazyHere();
        return true;
    }
    doSomethingMinorHere();
    return false;
}
```

Firstly, I have seen a lot of code that names their functions like `isValid(input)`. but let's say if it's not valid, i want the function to do different things. now, the other thing is that: i will be using this function multiple times.

So, in my mind, naming something like `isValid()` means that it doesn't do any logic, it just simply does some checks, and doesn't do anything fancy.

but naming something like `validateObject()` makes me think that it should be a void function that can do different things, but of course, not return a boolean.

so my question is: what is a proper name for this particular type of function?

**UPDATE:

Firstly, thanks for the suggestions on breaking it into two functions. the only reason i don't prefer it is that `someObject` can have multiple states that cause it to be valid or invalid or whatever. hence, `someObject.isCaseOne()` and `someObject.isCaseTwo()`. so if i were to check each state, i'd prolly have to make an enum for multiple states of an object? which i feel like is introducing unnecessary code :(

Comment: Have you considered breaking the function in two? Validate, and (separately) take action on invalid values?

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd use two separate functions: One to validate, and a *separate* function to do something in case of an invalid value.

If you *really really* want to combine them, then I'd make it really explicit, like: `validateAndIfInvalidThenX`. (And even then, I'd have two separate functions, and it would just call them.)

Comment: see, if you try to validate, there are MULTIPLE cases of what `someObject` can be, and you want to do something different in each result. i dont want to make an enum to define each different scenario of `someObject.isCaseOne()` -- that would just add unnecessary code, i feel like, but i can be convinced otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

name it `fixIfInvalid`

where 'fix' is whatever it's going to do in the event the input was invalid.  For example `capitalizeIfInvalid`

Agree with TJ that it is usually better to have two functions.  But there are always exceptions to 'usually'.

Edit:  In most cases I would suggest this function should return the object that is getting fixed (or not).

So,

```
ImaginaryFormInputClass myFormInput = WebPage.readInput();

myFormInput.fixIfInvalid().submitToDatabase();
// OR
Database.submit(myFormInput.fixIfInvalid());
```

Regarding your last comment about having to check `someObject.isCaseOne()` and `someObject.isCaseTwo()` ... this is precisely the job of a `someObject.checkIsValid()` function - you can use that function to call the other functions to check the object's state, and make an overall decision based on which of the functions passed (this is normally no more than 2 or 3).

Methods call other methods for the purpose of combining method calls to make things simpler, while keeping the code to do different things in different places.

It has been considered a basic 'best practice' of software engineering for years, if not decades, to solve the problem you are describing by having one function that validates things, and another that fixes invalid things.

There are exceptions to every general rule but without a clearer idea of why your project might fit into one of those exceptions, it is hard to get any more specific.   Without a clear understanding of why you want to go against this convention, it seems like you are going around the long way and making things more complicated in your efforts to simplify something else.

Comment: to me, that reads as a void function though :( any verb in the first word of a function seems to be an action, and that is usually void?

Comment: they name functions like `isThis()` or `hasSomething()` or `shouldDoThis()` and it's very clear that it returns a true or false.

Comment: @DavidT.: It basically *is* an action. This seems like a quite good name. The tension you're feeling is the result of conflating two different things (checking and correcting).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder absolutely. do you happen to know if ANdroid APIs typically can combine those two things, and if they do, what they name functions?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i've upvoted your answer. thanks for the suggestion. i was curious for specifics because with objective-C on iOS, the method naming is VERY LONG. however let's say you use scripting languages. i'm sure you've seen exactly how concise those variables can be.